# With AngularCLI 6+, What is the xxx value in ng g universal xxx used for?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What is the `morningharwood-server` doing in this example?  is it represented in the code anywhere?

`ng generate universal morningharwood-server --client-project morningharwood`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, on previous version (Angular cli 1.x) when you used

```
ng generate universal XXX
```

you could find in your .angular-cli.json something like this:

```
"platform": "server",
"name": "XXX"
```

But now if you try to do

```
ng generate universal XXX
```

You will receive an error message, this is because now you can have more than one project generated with angular cli in the same folder. That's why now it's used --client-project, to specify to which project we want to add Angular Universal.

So putting that name does absolutely nothing.
p.s I hope you understand me, my English is not so good.